# Angular 2 One page example

Tags: angularjs, angular

Trying to build a one page app, it will have a search div then a results div.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    // Div visability.
    searchVisible = true;
    resultsVisible = false;
}


<div class="container">
        <search *ngIf="searchVisible == true"></search>
        <results [resultsVisible]="resultsVisible" *ngIf="resultsVisible == true"></results>
</div>
```

Once results component get data back from the search form, it will switch resultsVisible to true so I am passing resultsVisible from AppComponent to ResultsComponent.

However this is not working atm.

Im not sure if that hows other people do it but I am still having trouble to hide/show the divs correctly.

Can someone please show me an example of how a "one page" app works in Angular 2 with hiding/showing elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[hidden]`. Something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <search [hidden]="!searchVisible"></search>
    <results [hidden]="!resultsVisible"></results>
</div>
```

Comment: It is possible to do Fading in/out of a div using that method?

Comment: You should be able to use any standard css transitions you want.

Comment: Tried a few ways but couldnt get it working ... not sure how to target the div or <search>, <results>

was trying to do something like this:
hidden {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
but that didnt work

Comment: add a class such as `.results` and use `.results` and `.results[hidden]` as your selectors for the transitions.

Comment: Got it working however angular2 hidden uses display:none not opacity. this is my code

.transition {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

.transition[hidden] {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
}